# Is there any benefit to increasing the maximum orphan tx in bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-pools

I'm still learning how all of this stuff works. I'm running a v0.15.1 full node. While I was watching the debug output, I noticed that orphan tx were being discarded because the maximum had been reached. To see what would happen, I restarted bitcoind with maxorphantx=1024.

Is there any benefit to the bitcoin community by preserving a larger number of orphan tx or am I just wasting memory?

Note: I forgot to mention that my copy of the blockchain is up to date. The orphans I'm seeing aren't because I'm missing blocks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any benefit to the bitcoin community by preserving a larger
>   number of orphan tx

What kind of benefit/profit/etc can gain the community by the increased mempool for orphan transactions on one node? Literally, none.

> or am I just wasting memory?

This is your donation to the network.